# How to extend entity with the runtime property in shopware 6

Tags: php, shopware6

I want to add a single auto-increment column into the core `order_delivery` table in Shopware 6.
To implement that I built the following extension:

```
#[Autoconfigure(tags: ['shopware.entity.extension'])]
class OrderDeliveryReferenceExtension extends EntityExtension
{
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            (new IntField('reference_number', 'referenceNumber'))
                ->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Runtime()),
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return OrderDeliveryDefinition::class;
    }
}
```

This column exists in the table and it is populated with the data but I cannot read them with `$this->delivery->get('referenceNumber')`. I got the "Property 'referenceNumber' not found" error.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you extend the database table as well? Your `EntityExtension` only extends the class which represents your database table.

[You can follow this example from the shopware docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities.html#adding-a-field-with-a-database). It shows how to add a new field to an existing entity. Your example won't work because of:

> Since you must not extend the product table with a new column, you'll
> have to add a new table which contains the new data for the product.
> This new table will then be associated using a OneToOne association

Comment: Thanks, I already understood that I cannot extend the existing table but must create a new table. It is pity, but we can do nothing with that :)